# Can't change Finder background image

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I can't change my background image in Finder! I keep dragging the image over, but it just doesn't seem to work, and I don't really know why. It's just a regular JPEG, but the same thing happens with a PNG. What can I do to fix it? You can see a GIF that shows what happens [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BzYY6D-oLaqdRC1Iclc0STU1eVk).

Comment: Does this happen with all folders or only the standards ones (like Documents or Music)?

Comment: I just restarted my Mac and it completely solved my problem. That's odd.